# Reactor: how to get items from combineLatest on fluxes that a subset of can be empty

Tags: java, reactive-programming, project-reactor, combinelatest

I am using `Flux.combineLatest(combinator, stream1, stream2, ...)` method to get latest items from each input stream.
This will emit an item only once each input stream emits at least one value, in other words, no item will flow out if there's at least one empty flux, whereas I combine fluxes with two types of data:

- one that is required to contain data before `combineLatest` emits
- another that is optional - lack of items on it shouldn't block emissions from `combineLatest`

Once optional fluxes start to emit data, they should be treated just like the other fluxes with required data.

I went through reactor docs and couldn't find a suitable operator that would do the job.

The only workaround idea I have is to prepend (`startWith`) optional fluxes with some dummy data that I would then identify and exclude in a combinator function, but it's not very appealing to me.

Comment: Yes, you need all sources of `combineLatest` to emit once, otherwise you don't have a full row of data to be combined into a single one. Indeed, the workaround is to prepend probably empty sources with "dummy" data and handle it in the combiner function. There is no other way around the issue.

Comment: Thanks for feedback. I can think of one edge case already with this approach: with only ‘optional’ fluxes as input, combineLatest will emit an ‘initial’ item anyway, so would have to filter it out on the output of it. 
Just wondering if there could be a way to add a flux to combineLatest only once it’s started to emit…